# C# Service: Error 1053: The service did not respond to the start or control request in a timely fashion

Tags: c#, service

I have a problem with a self programmed windows service for .Net 6 that inherits from BackgroundService.

While other services I have programmed for .Net 6 run without problems, this service causes problems at startup.

The service reports an error 1053 and thinks that it does not respond within a time period. Sure, extensive initializations take place at startup, but they take a maximum of 2 seconds on my computer.

`

```
namespace WooComMesserschmidt
{
    internal class Worker : BackgroundService
    {
        private readonly HttpClient                     Client          = new()
        private string                                  BaseAddress     = string.Empty;
        private readonly IConfiguration                 Configuration;
        private string                                  ConfigFile      = string.Empty;
        private readonly Dictionary<string, dynamic?>   _ConfigPar;
        internal static  Dictionary<string, string>     ConfigPar       = new();
        private readonly ILogger<Worker>                _logger;

        public struct LogInfo
        {
            public ILogger<Worker>? Logger;
            public string?          LogFile;

            public LogInfo(ILogger<Worker>? logger, string logfile)
            {
                Logger  = logger;
                LogFile = logfile;
            }
        }

        public static LogInfo logInfo;

        public Worker(ILogger<Worker> logger, IConfiguration configuration, Dictionary<string, dynamic?> configpar)
        {
            Configuration   = configuration;
            _ConfigPar      = configpar;
            _logger         = logger;

            Init();
        }
...
```

`

In the method "Init()" relatively extensive tasks take place (on my PC it takes about 2 seconds). If these are through, it goes on here:

`

```
protected override async Task ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken stoppingToken)
        {
            if (int.TryParse(ConfigPar[cpQueryInterval], out int QueryInterval) == false)
            {
                QueryInterval = QueryIntervalStd;
                Log.LogInformation(logInfo, $"Abfrageintervall konnte nicht ermittelt werden. Es wird daher der Standardwert von {QueryInterval} Millisekunden verwendet. Prüfen Sie die Angaben in der Parameterdatei.");
            }

            Log.LogInformation(logInfo, $"{Process.GetCurrentProcess().ProcessName} gestartet.");
            Log.LogInformation(logInfo, $"Worker arbeitet mit Abfrageintervall von {QueryInterval} Millisekunden.");

            while (stoppingToken.IsCancellationRequested == false)
            {
                await ProcessNewOrders();

                await UpdateProducts();

                Dhl_Polling();

                await Task.Delay(QueryInterval, stoppingToken);
            }
        }
...
```

`

The service is supposed to fetch orders from an eShop every few minutes, update items and process DHL shipments.

Well, when I start the program manually in the command line (i.e. not as a service), everything works as expected. Now I have registered the program as a service and every time I try to start the service I get the following error:

Error 1053: The service did not respond to the start or control request in a timely fashion

We started everything in Main:

`

```
private static async Task<int> Main(string[] args)
        {
            try
            {
                IHost host = Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
                    .UseWindowsService(options =>
                    {
                        options.ServiceName = ServiceName;
                    })
                    .ConfigureServices(services =>
                    {
                        services.AddSingleton<Dictionary<string, dynamic?>> (_ConfigPar);

                        services.AddHostedService<Worker>();
                    })
                    .Build();

                await host.RunAsync();

                Log.LogInformation((LogInfo)_ConfigPar[cpLogInfo], $"{Process.GetCurrentProcess().ProcessName} beendet.");

                if (Debugger.IsAttached == true)
                {
                    Console.ReadLine();
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"{ex}{Environment.NewLine}{Environment.NewLine}");
...
```

`

How do I proceed to avoid this error?

Other services I have programmed, which are also based on .Net 6, work without any problems. However, with these the initialization is faster. But 2 seconds?

I have also entered the following in the registry:

Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control

ServicesPipeTimeout (REG_DWORD): 0x180000

But this did not help.

Many thanks

René

Internet search, other forums and documentation

Comment: You can try to debug your service to check if it's blocking on some operation: start Visual Studio as admin then on debug menu choose attach to process. Usually the servicies are running in a context which is different from the user one, so maybe some resource you suppose to be available is not

Comment: OK, problem solved. The error message had driven me astray and I was looking in the wrong place for the cause of the error. Now I proceeded systematically step by step: at the very beginning, the service crashes without doing anything. The error was due to the "displayname" of the service - this may be maximum 80 characters long, while I used 110 characters. I didn't know that and the error message also said something completely different.

Thanks for your help! The weekend is saved!

René